# Location of an object with a given class in the timepicker addon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

Please look this link : (Jquery Time Picker Add-on)

[timepicker example](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) 
([Time picker addon](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon))

On line 359, I need to understand the following code:

```
'<dd class="ui_tpicker_time" id="ui_tpicker_time_' + dp_id + '"' + ((o.showTime)
                         ? '' : noDisplay) + '></dd>' +
```

I did a search for "ui_tpicker_time" but couldn't find where the class is located inside that above add on JS files.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: the question about the code and the 2 lines below are unrelated

Comment: @SmartestVEGA - Please look at your question now I have given the context of the code you are asking about. Before it was impossible to guess what you were talking about

Comment: Actually correcting your question almost answered it too - look at the documentation in the link I gave in your own question

Comment: thanks, i have a question ban now, can u up-votes my question, i have rewritten in understandable manner!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It adds the bolded code

var noDisplay = ' **style="display:none;"**',

to the dd tag if the boolean o.showtime is set to false like this

`$('#example5').datetimepicker({showTime: false }`

which I guess you would only do if your visitor wanted to turn it off

Comment: thanks, i have a question ban now, can u up-votes my question, i have rewritten in understandable manner!

Comment: But still i can see -2 votes for my question ..any idea why?

Comment: Only one vote er person. so 3 persons downvoted...